# getting error "user.save is not a function" while trying to update a doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am updating a document according to the code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var user = require('./user');

router.put('/:username/email',
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("control check");
        next();
    },
    email.acquire,
    function(req, res) {
        console.log("control check");
        var username = req.params.username;
        var address = req.body.email;
        console.log(address);
        user.find({
            'username': username
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                throw (err);
                console.log('ERROR WHILE PUT EMAIL');
            } else {
                console.log('success while PUT email');
                user.email = address;
                user.save(function(err, updatedUser) {
                    if (err) throw (err);

                    res.status(200).send(updatedUser)
                });
            }
        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

but am getting the error:

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: user.save is not a function

the code for user.js is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = user;
```

I already tried to create an object out of the model but to no avail.

and yes there exist a collection called "user".

Comment: Also, your collection name in db will be `users` not `user`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `user` returned from the `find()` callback will be an array of mongoose documents, hence why it is complaining. Either use the **[`findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findone_findOne)** method which returns a single Mongoose document that has the save method or use **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate)** for an atomic update.

You also need to be unambigious with variable naming since you have duplicate `user` variables, one for the mongoose model and another for the callback parameter.

Using **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate)** follows:

```
user.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'username': username }, 
    { '$set': { 'email', address } },
    { 'new': true /*, 'upsert': true */ }
    function(err, updatedUser) {
        if (err) {
            throw (err);
            console.log('ERROR WHILE PUT EMAIL');
        } else {
            console.log('success while PUT email');
            res.status(200).send(updatedUser)
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

User.find returns array of the result, Use findOne. Don't use the same variable name it creates confusion.

```
user.findOne({
    'username': username
}, function (err, userData) {
    if (err) {
        throw (err);
        console.log('ERROR WHILE PUT EMAIL');
    } else {
        if (userData) {
            console.log('success while PUT email');
            userData.email = address;
            userData.save(function (err, updatedUser) {
                if (err) throw (err);

                res.status(200).send(updatedUser)
            });
        }else{
            res.status(200).send('Some response')
        }
    }
});
```